# PHP popen pipes becoming null after one iteration

Tags: php, popen

I'm trying to generate 12 worker processes to work on various chunks of my data using `popen` in PHP under Windows. Here's my code... it's pretty generic.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit(0);

    $workers = array_fill(0, 12, null);

    $currChunk = 56;
    $working = true;

    while($working == true) {
        $working = false;

        foreach($workers as $worker) {
            if($worker == null) {
                if($currChunk < 265) {
                    $worker = popen('C:\php\php.exe "C:\users\administrator\desktop\do one chunk.php" '.$currChunk, 'r');
                    echo("\r\nStarted a worker on chunk ".$currChunk);
                    $currChunk ++;

                    $working = true;
                }
            } else {
                if(feof($worker)){
                    pclose($worker);
                    $worker = null;
                    echo("A worker finished!");
                } else {
                    fread($worker, 1);

                    $working = true;
                }
            }
        }

        sleep(.01);
    }
?>
```

What's happening here is that the script just continually starts new workers until it hits the limit of 265, then it ends. It never waits for them to actually finish.

I've tried `echo`ing the value of `$worker` after the `popen` and I get back "Resource Instance ID #XXX" which tells me that's working fine.

I've also tried `echo`ing "here!" for the `else` section of code that should execute if the worker is not set to null... that code never executes, even though it should.

What's up? Am I blind?

Comment: Next step: Parallelize workers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`foreach` operates on a copy of the array.  You need to reference `$worker` using `&` to modify the elements of the original array:

```
foreach($workers as &$worker) {
```

The alternative is:

```
foreach($workers as $key => $worker) {
    $workers[$key] = 'something';
}
```

Comment: Holy crap on a cracker. I don't think I've ever tried to write to the variables generated by `foreach`. Generally, I'm looping through arrays based on indexes. Wow. Thanks!

Comment: Added the key method as alternative.